# Get values of 2 columns as single value when separated with '|'

Tags: sql

I want to have the values of two columns as a single value but separated with '|' and to also skip the hyphen if values are not present in the particular column.

For example:

[image]

The output should be like below,

```
1|2
2
1|2
2
1|2
```

Comment: which db you are using ??

Comment: SELECT column1 || "|" || column 2 FROM someTable

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

Concatenating a string with  `NULL` value returns `NULL`. `ISNULL()` will set a default in case of `NULL`, while `NULLIF` will return `NULL` in case of a fullfilled condition:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Column1 VARCHAR(1),Column2 VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('1','2'),('-','2'),('1','2'),('-','-'),('2','-'),('1','2');

SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(Column1 + '|','-|'),'')
      +ISNULL(NULLIF(Column2,'-'),'')
FROM @mockup
```

The result

```
1|2
2
1|2

2|
1|2
```

Comment: When there are five columns, I made query like below

SELECT 
 ISNULL(NULLIF(Column1 + '|','-|'),'')+
 ISNULL(NULLIF(Column2 + '|','-|'),'')+
 ISNULL(NULLIF(Column3 + '|','-|'),'')+
 ISNULL(NULLIF(Column4 + '|','-|'),'')+
 ISNULL(NULLIF(Column5,'-'),'')
FROM ABC_Table

Somewhere the out put comes with '|' at end.Please help me to to avoid getting '|' at end.Example 1|2|3|4|  , here I dont want '|' after 4 . . . . Thanks

Comment: @MohammadMujtaba Please avoid chameleon questions. My answer covers your initial question completely... What you should do: If this question is solved, please accept the best answer (your free choice) by clicking the check below the vote counter. This pays points to the answerer and to you. Then start a new question. Copy the *mockup* declaration above, add columns and sample data, and start a new question (with expected output). Place a link here and you'll get help immediately!

Comment: Thanks Shnugo ! your answer(given query) helped me to fix my issues.

Comment: will take care in future

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings you can use "||". For example:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN column2
         WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN column1
         ELSE column1 || "|" || column2
       END 
  FROM someTable
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is that whenever there is hyphen(-) in any of the column values, just skip the hyphen and print value of the column having value.If both the column having hyphen, then skip that rows completely.

Comment: @MohammadMujtaba I edited my answer. Does that help?